# Fragment накладывается на preference fragment

Tags: java, android

В navigation drawer создаю два фрагмента обычный и с настройками, при переходе из фрагмента настроек на другой он накладывается

### SettingsFragment

public class SettingsFragment extends Fragment {

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.container_fragments, new Settings())
            .commit();
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    //getActivity().setTitle(R.string.settings_title);
}

/*@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.settings, container, false);
    return view;
}*/

public static class Settings extends PreferenceFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getActivity().setTitle(R.string.settings_title);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);
    }
}
```

}

---

Класс для работы с Navigation Drawer

---

```
public abstract class Navigation extends AppCompatActivity {

private DrawerLayout drawer;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle t;
private NavigationView nv;


@LayoutRes
protected int getLayoutResId() {
    return R.layout.activity_fragment;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(getLayoutResId());
    drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    t = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, R.string.Open, R.string.Close);

    drawer.addDrawerListener(t);
    t.syncState();

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


    nv = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    nv.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            int id = item.getItemId();
            switch (id) {
                case R.id.account:
                    /*FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
                    Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.account_fragment);
                    if (fragment == null) {
                        fragment = new AccountFragment();
                    }
                    fm.beginTransaction()
                            .add(R.id.account_fragment, fragment)
                            .commit();*/
                    openFragment("account");
                    drawer.closeDrawers();
                    break;
                /*case R.id.recipes:
                    Toast.makeText(Navigation.this, "Recipes", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    openFragment("R.id.recipes");
                    break;*/
                case R.id.settings:
                    openFragment("settings");
                    drawer.closeDrawers();
                    break;
                default:
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    if (t.onOptionsItemSelected(item))
        return true;

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


public void openFragment(String frag) {
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentByTag(frag);

    if (fragment == null) {
        switch (frag) {
            case "account":
                fragment = new AccountFragment();
                break;
           /* case "R.id.recipes":
                break;*/
            case "settings":
                fragment = new SettingsFragment();
                break;
            }
        fm.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container_fragments, fragment, frag)
                .commit();

    }
}
```

}

---

AccountFragment

```
public class AccountFragment extends Fragment {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getActivity().setTitle(R.string.Acoount_title);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.account_fragment, container, false);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

}

Account fragment накладывается на Settings Fragment

[![
вот][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CbE4x.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CbE4x.png)

Comment: У вас что-то странное написано. Есть некий SettingsFragment который при создании в активити добавляет Settings, который тоже фрагмент.... Кажется вам просто не нужно этого делать.

Comment: почему вы не вызываете из активити напрямую фрагмент Settings, а какой то SettingsFragment, который не делает ничего, кроме замены на другой фрагмент, зачем так? нужно решить сначала эту проблему, потом смотреть, что на что накладывается, в текущем виде решать что то с наложениями бессмысленно, так как сама реализация неприемлема